# Unexpected count results

Tags: mysql

I have the following query which is returning total number of entries in the requests column in the requests table for each given user, rather than the number of requests marked as played for any given user.

```
SELECT 
    t1.status, t1.FirstName

    t2.CountPlayed
FROM 
    RequestsTable t1
    INNER JOIN 

    (SELECT t1.FirstName, Count(t1.status ='played') AS CountPlayed 
     FROM RequestsTable t1

    GROUP BY t1.FirstName) 

     t2 ON t1.FirstName = t2.FirstName

WHERE t1.status = 'played'
```

**Desired results: eg**

Fred: 2 (played out of total 6 requests)

Ginger: 1 (played out of total 4 requests)

Lenny: 2 (played out of total 3 requests)

**Actual results:**

Fred = 6

Ginger = 4

Lenny = 3

Comment: Move the condition to the WHERE clause and just use `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel That was already posted as an answer.

Comment: @Barmar For some reason I didn't see that answer. I still have the tab open with Uueerdos answer, my comment and nothing else. Now I see.. it was deleted and undeleted.

Answer (score 2):

That `count` isn't working the way you think it is. You need to filter using `where` first.

```
...
INNER JOIN 

(SELECT t1.FirstName, count(*) AS CountPlayed 
 FROM RequestsTable t1
 WHERE t1.status = 'played'
 GROUP BY t1.FirstName)
....
```

Actually you can further simplify the whole thing to just one query:

```
SELECT 
    t1.FirstName, count(*)
FROM 
    RequestsTable t1
WHERE t1.status = 'played'
GROUP BY t1.FirstName;
```

Comment: Note that the first query will return duplicates while the second won't. And you can/should remove `t1.status` from SELECT since we know it might only be `'played'` but can cause issues with `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode.

Comment: I did not know about that grouping issue. Thanks. I adjusted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try `SUM` instead of `COUNT`. `COUNT` counts 0/false; it only ignores NULL.

Comment: This would be appropriate in a query that's trying to get the count of different conditions. If you're just trying to count one thing, @BrianEcker's solution is better.

Comment: Thanks guys and galls. All of your answers have helped to straighten me out on this. I do actually want to do a second count in this query, so need to experiment a little further. But you've set me on the right track. Will creidt best answer as soon as poss.